# Good book on c# style?

Tags: c#, coding-style

what book would you recommend to improve one's c# style of writing? I know Code Complete has a few tips on style and organizing code but it's not specific to c#.

Answer (score 16):

[Framework Design Guidelines](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321545613), 2nd Edition.

Comment: +1 - This is a DEFINITE requirement for anybody who either gets paid to developer .NET code or whose code may have to be maintained by someone else.

Answer (score 7):

Not a book, but check out [StyleCop](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)

Comment: +1- that was going to be my answer, but you'd already answered it.

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the iDesign coding standards at:
http://www.idesign.net/idesign/DesktopDefault.aspx

Comment: Juval's style is a solid baseline.  The book "Programming .NET Components" is also fairly high on my "must-read" .NET books.  It's got lots of good advice on style and practices.

Answer (score 3):

MSDN has some good [guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229042.aspx) for developing C# classes.

Comment: These are essentialy an online version of what's in the Framework Design Guidelines book without the "annotations" contained in the book.

Answer (score 2):

[Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321245660) by Bill Wagner, as well as the sequel, [More Effective C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321485890).

Answer (score 2):

[CLR Via C# by Jeffrey Richter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735627045) contains all the 2.0 patterns you need to follow in order to produce good code.  Helped me immensely.

Answer (score 1):

[C# 4.0 in a Nutshell, Fourth Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596800959) is great book

Answer (score 0):

[C# Concisely](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321154185)   very thorough

Answer (score 0):

[Elements of C# Style](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Elements-C-Style-Kenneth-Baldwin/dp/0521671590/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&s=books&qid=1304188888&sr=8-1) is a good primer.

While it may not go into as much detail as other books that are available but I've definetly got my moneys worth from it - highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend [Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert Martin. Yes, it's not C#-specific, and yes, it will improve one's C# style of writing. It might be a good idea to continue with [Agile Software Development, Principles, Patterns, and Practices](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0135974445) book by the same author.

And here is 1 hour video from uncle Bob at Øredev conference [Clean Code III: Functions](http://www.viddler.com/explore/oredev/videos/15/)

PS: Shameless plug. I developed a [site](http://www.yasiv.com/#/search?q=Clean%20code) which answers exactly this question: "Which book is of higher importance in given area?". I get the data from Amazon, and draw a network of books. The more links one book has the higher its importance. Thanks to this site I also found "[Agile Principles, Patterns, and Practices in C#](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131857258)", again by Robert Martin, but I prefer the original book.